# Allow page break in reference list

Tags: bibliographies, page-breaking

I am using the elsart-num bibliography style in an article document class. I find that my references overflow the page (only half of the citations show up). Any clues as to what I might be missing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: without an example (it helps to _always_ post a small document that shows the problem) it is hard to say but the description sounds like the list is in a box eg from `minipage` or `\parbox` or ...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the hint. That solved it! I had a \samepage command which was the issue.

Answer (score 3):

By default reference lists do break over a page, so if yours isn't breaking it must be in a box such as `minipage` or `\parbox` or breaking prevented in other ways such as for example (confirmed in comments) `samepage`).